Proof Check:if $a+b\sqrt c$ is a root of a poly in $Q[x]$,so is $a-b\sqrt c$
The question: If $a+b\sqrt c$ is a root of a poly in $Q[x]$,so is $a-b\sqrt c$,in which $a,b,c$ is rational number, and $\sqrt c$ is irrational.
My proof:Let $p(x)$ be the minimum polynomial of $a+b\sqrt c$ and $F$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $Q$ and therefore normal .
Since $a-b\sqrt c=2a-a-b\sqrt c$ ,the minimum polynomial of $a-b\sqrt c$,denoted by $q(x)$ ,splits in $F$.Thus,the splitting field of $p,q$ over Q is actually a subfield of $F$.However,$F$ is actually $Q(u_1,\dots,u_n)$,$u_i$ is root of $p$, which means it is an intersection of all fields containing $Q$ and $u_i$.So up to now we can conclude that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have the same roots .Therefore we finished our proof.
It is my first try in field theory.I wonder if my proof is correct.If it is incorrect,how could i amend it.
Appreciate!

The claim is wrong, take $a=b=0$, $c=4$. Then $\sqrt{c}$ is rational. Please add all the assumptions you have.

But in the question there is the assumption that $\sqrt{c}$ is irrational, no?

@MartinBrandenburg I do claim that $\sqrt c$ is irrational and the proposition is true under this circumstance.

@schiepy there is,actually.

Sorry I misread. I thought it's part of the claim.

The key to observe here is that if $a+b\sqrt{c} =0$ then $a=b=0$. Next observe that if $p(a+b\sqrt{c}) = A+B\sqrt {c} $ then $p(a-b\sqrt{c}) =A-B\sqrt{c} $. Combine these ideas to arrive at a proof.

I think that your proof is incorrect or at least inaccurate. Just because $q$ splits over $F$ we cannot conclude that it shares its roots with $p$. Here's an example:
Take the polynomial $x^8+6x^4+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by
Irreducibility of $x^8+6x^4+1$
If $\alpha$ is a root of this polynomial in its splitting field, then it can be shown that
$$Q(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha^4+1}{\alpha^2}$$ is also in the splitting field, but is root of the polynomial $x^2+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Maybe I'm wrong, but this example seems to share all the assumptions you make in the proof.
I think it would be much easier to show that the minimal polynomial of $a+b\sqrt{c}$ is quadratic, i.e. is of the form $x^2+dx+f$ and then showing that $a-b\sqrt{c}$ is also root of this polynomial.

yes，this is a counter example.I actually know how to solve it with limited knowledge.similar to conjugate complex roots.I just quiet  curious about if we could solve problems about polynomials with field theory,especially when we care about polys so much there.

@GaryNg, your intuition on conjugate complex roots is spot on. The main concept is conjugacy under field automorphisms.
